# How get the absolute, floating-point width of an element use getBoundingClientRect().width

Tags: jquery, html

Am trying to get the absolute, floating-point width of an element and am told I need to use `getBoundingClientRect().width`. For whatever reason I cannot succeed in getting it to work from a JQuery (ver. 1.11.3) element...

```
var rect = $("#id").get(0); //tried this too $("#id")[0]
console.log(rect.getBoundingClientRect());
```

Returns...

```
rect.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
```

Wat now???

Comment: Can you recreate the problem via code snippet/jsfiddle so that we can debug?

Comment: jQuery internally uses `.getBoundingClientRect()`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a6fc0b16511c70472ebb3dd9469d08566969ac88/src/css.js#L123

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/tc9vejw7/ You'll have to show a demo that replicates the problem.